# Parse Facebook Integration

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm trying to use Parse to create a social app with Facebook integration. The only problem is that the tutorial Parse has uses xib and not Storyboard, so in the code after signing into Facebook it uses the loadnibnamed function which I am not able to do because I have a storyboard.  Any Ideas?

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableHeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a storyboard then the nib will have already loaded. You can just put the Facebook code inside of your view controller and remove that line.